# MySQL delete and update multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

Say I have an entity A in one table and an arbitrary number of other entities B related to it in other table.

I have a situation where I need to replace all those B entities with a list of new B entities in a way that there should be no duplicates.

Simple way would be to issue a DELETE query first to remove all the old ones and then an INSERT query for new ones but I wonder if there's a way to do it in one query?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html) to replace rows in a table.

Comment: it will only work in case of duplicates, I also need to delete all the old non-duplicates. REPLACE wont affect them.

Comment: You should really add that into your question then.  Your question doesn't say you need to delete all entities in B that aren't connected to A, you said just replace with no duplicates.